# My code doesn't work on Safari

Tags: jquery, css, google-chrome, safari

viewing this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nnjkj7qf/) in Google Chrome works fine and the slide down and up effect works, but in Safari it doesn't. What am I doing wrong? Is it the jQuery or the css?

Here's the code:

jQuery:

```
$(function() {
  $('.dropdown').hide();
  $('.dropdown-toggle').click(function(e) {
    $('.dropdown').slideToggle(400);
    $('.dropdown-toggle').slideDown('active');
    $('.dropdown').toggleClass('is-active');
    return false;
  });
  $(document).click(function() {
    if ($('.dropdown').is(':visible')) {
      $('.dropdown', this).slideUp();
      $('.dropdown').removeClass('is-active');
    }
  });
});
```

CSS:

```
body {
  padding: 2em;
}
a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #000;
}
nav {
  position: relative;
}
.dropdown-toggle {
  padding: .5em 1em;
  background: #777;
  border-radius: .2em .2em 0 0;
}
.dropdown {
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: .5em;
  background: #777;
  min-width: 12em;
  padding: 0;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-60px);
  -ms-transform: translateY(-60px);
  transform: translateY(-60px);
  transition: transform .3s
}
.dropdown.is-active {
  -webkit-transform: translateY(30px);
  -ms-transform: translateY(30px);
  transform: translateY(30px);
  display: block
}
ul.dropdown li {
  list-style-type: none;
}
ul.dropdown a {
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: .5em 1em;
  display: block;
}
```

HTML:

```
<nav><a class="dropdown-toggle" href="#" title="Menu">Menu</a>
  <ul class="dropdown">
    <li><a href="#">Menu Item</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Menu</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Settings</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Search</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Thanks!

Comment: It is working for me. Which version of Safari are you using?

Comment: It's also working for me on Version 9.0 (11601.1.56). As @David said, which version are you using ?

Comment: @David the only one available for Windows, version 5.1.7

Comment: @FidanHakaj version 5.1.7 for Windows.

Comment: @J.Doe The menu animation is working fine on my Safari. Careful, Windows's version is probably an old one as Apple stopped its development AFAIK.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IMO your question is confusing. This sentence:

> the slide down and up effect works, but in Safari it doesn't.

is misleading. Actually, the `transform` property **does work** and it has the expected behaviour (it "slides down and up") both on your version of Safari (5.1.7) on Windows (I have just tested out) and on modern versions of Safari on OS X.

The *CSS* property `transform` is available on Safari since its 3.1 version, as you can check out [here](http://caniuse.com/#feat=transforms2d).

What it is **not** working is the `transtion` effect. For that one you need a more updated Safari, read [here](http://caniuse.com/#search=transition).

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for the info, and to comment on the confusing sentence I didn't know which part wasn't functioning right so I spoke in general.

Comment: @J.Doe: please, mark the answer as "accepted" if you think the information I gave you is correct.

Answer (score 0):

I could not add a comment so I'll answer instead.

could you try with a higher version of safari to test compatibility.

could be due to the outdated javascript engine ?

Comment: I can't have a newer version on Windows because there are no more updates.